# QoS bandwidth via SNMP

Tags: snmp

I currently have a script to glean QoS data from differing cisco routers and this is working well but missing the bandwidth data for each class.

I can see that the data is available in that querying:

```
enterprises.9.9.166.1.9.1.1.1.1608 = INTEGER: 425
```

Returns the correct bandwidth for this particular class [425kb]. I have seen this index elsewhere:

```
enterprises.9.9.166.1.5.1.1.2.6933270.5456067 = Gauge32: 1608
```

With '6933270' being one of the indexes associated with the interface I am interested in.

How though do I 'learn' the second index '5456067' or is there another way to derive the class bandwidth?

I have scoured Google which has me at this point but I am unable to get any closer to the second index. Multiple snmpwalks grepping the second index show no light either in that I can find no way to relate to this from existing known data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the wrong oid entry. enterprises.9.9.166.1.5.1.1.2 stands for cisco cbQosConfigIndex from mib, if you want to get the bandwidth, you should use the 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.9.1.1.2 which means QueueingBandwidthUnits instead.